# JAXB: Place XML tag on abstract classes

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I am using an interface from a third party and they have a peculiar (to my mind at least) XML format for request/response and notification. The XML needs to look like this:

```
<Message>
  <Version>3.1</Version>
  <Request>
    <Request_Name>
      <RequestID> Request ID </RequestID>
      ...
    </Request_Name>
  </Request>
</Message>
```

The `Request` tag could also be one of `Notification` or `Response`. All `Messages` will have only one of these three. `Request` and `Response` both have `RequestID`. `Response` has `ReturnValue` as well. `Notification`s have a `Session`.

In order to prevent duplication I wanted to create an abstract class for each of these three types, and it almost works! What I can marshall to and unmarshall from looks like this:

```
<Message>
  <Version>3.1</Version>
  <Request_Name>
    <RequestID> Request ID </RequestID>
    ...
  </Request_Name>
</Message>
```

Note the missing `Request` tag! Same for `Notification` and `Response`. All information is there but these wrapper tags are killing me!

***The Question:***
*Can I put an XML tag on the abstract class? Or do I need make it non-abstract and create another top-level abstract class as the "real" abstract base class?*

I haven't much experience with JAXB, so I'm hoping there is a simple way to do this. I tried making the `request` field on message an `XMLElement` instead but that only changes the `Request_Name` tag to `Request` and adds a type specification.

My code is basically as below, with setters and CTORs taken out for brevity.

The base `Message` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class Message {
    @XmlElement(required = true, name = "Version") private String version;
    private Request request;
    private Response response;
    private Notification notification;

    @XmlElementRef(required = false)
    public Request getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(required = false)
    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(required = false)
    public Notification getNotification() {
        return notification;
    }
}
```

Abstract `Request` class. Similar for `Notification` and `Response`:

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
public abstract class Request {
    private String requestId;

    @XmlElement(name = "RequestID", required = true)
    public String getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }
}
```

An example `Request` implementation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RegForAllNotificationsRequest")
public class RegForAllNotificationsRequest extends Request {
    private long session;
    private boolean register;

    @XmlElement(name = "SessionToUse")
    public long getSession() {
        return session;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "Register")
    public boolean isRegister() {
        return register;
    }
}
```

The above gets marshalled something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message>
    <Version>8.3</Version>
    <RegForAllNotificationsRequest>
        <RequestID>94668</RequestID>
        <SessionToUse>548248</SessionToUse>
        <Register>true</Register>
    </RegForAllNotificationsRequest>
</Message>
```

Where I need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <Version>8.3</Version>
    <Request>
        <RegForAllNotificationsRequest>
            <RequestID>94668</RequestID>
            <SessionToUse>548248</SessionToUse>
            <Register>true</Register>
        </RegForAllNotificationsRequest>
    </Request>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a `RequestContainer` class that has the tag name **Request**. This class will contain the actual request implementation. This is required because, JAXB will render each class as a separate tag. The tag hierarchy is not built based on the class hierarchy.

The container class will look something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
public class RequestContainer {
   private Request request;
}
```

Similarly, for the `Notification` and `Response`. The `Message` class will contain an instance of the container classes for each like below:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class Message {
    @XmlElement(required = true, name = "Version") private String version;
    private RequestContainer request;
    private ResponseContainer response;
    private NotificationContainer notification;

    @XmlElementRef(required = false)
    public Request getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(required = false)
    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    @XmlElementRef(required = false)
    public Notification getNotification() {
        return notification;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is actually very close to what I ended up with. I will post my solution as well but will mark yours correct.